# Gson String to Object

Tags: java, android, gson

I am stuck on how to fix this problem, I think i understand the problem which is that the gson is in the incorrect format e.g. missing Bsid in this case. How would i fix it so if this problem so it doesnt happen again?

```
Error:E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: , PID: 32171 com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 65536 path $[555].bBsid
```

Code Being Used:

```
    if(json.length()== Integer.MAX_VALUE){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error");
            return null;
        } else {


            Log.i(TAG, json);

            Type arrayType = new TypeToken<List<WifiObject>>() {
            }.getType();
            Gson gson = new Gson();


            ArrayList<WifiObject> wifiObjectArrayList = new ArrayList<WifiObject>();
            List wifiObjectList = gson.fromJson(json, arrayType);
            for (int i = 0; i < wifiObjectList.size() - 1; i++) {

                if (wifiObjectList.get(i) != null) {
                    WifiObject wifiObject = (WifiObject) wifiObjectList.get(i);
                }

//                    Log.i(TAG, wifiObject.getBBSID());

//                    wifiObjectArrayList.add(wifiObject);
            }

            return wifiObjectArrayList;
        }
```

Object:

```
  public WifiObject(String bBSID, String sSID, String capabilites, Integer frequency, Integer level){
    //Instead of this.bssid for example because the setters already have Log's in them
    setBBSID(bBSID);
    setSSID(sSID);
    setCapabilites(capabilites);
    setFrequency(Integer.toString(frequency));
    setLevel(Integer.toString(level));

}
```

Trying to convert this:

```
 02-28 23:57:53.876 4259-4259/ I/WifiHandler: 
[{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:f0","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"2462","level":"-45","sSid":"eduroam"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:f1","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"2462","level":"-46","sSid":"KINGSWAP"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:f2","capabilities":"[ESS]","frequency":"2462","level":"-46","sSid":"The Cloud"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:f3","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][WPA-EAP-TKIP][ESS]","frequency":"2462","level":"-46","sSid":"PLOCAL"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:f4","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"2462","level":"-46","sSid":"SLaMFT"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:50","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"2437","level":"-53","sSid":"eduroam"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:ff","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"5520","level":"-53","sSid":"eduroam"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:fd","capabilities":"[ESS]","frequency":"5520","level":"-53","sSid":"The Cloud"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:53","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][WPA-EAP-TKIP][ESS]","frequency":"2437","level":"-54","sSid":"PLOCAL"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:51","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"2437","level":"-55","sSid":"KINGSWAP"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:52","capabilities":"[ESS]","frequency":"2437","level":"-55","sSid":"The Cloud"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:fb","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"5520","level":"-55","sSid":"SLaMFT"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:54","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"2437","level":"-55","sSid":"SLaMFT"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:5d","capabilities":"[ESS]","frequency":"5240","level":"-56","sSid":"The Cloud"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:fe","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"5520","level":"-56","sSid":"KINGSWAP"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:5e","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"5240","level":"-57","sSid":"KINGSWAP"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:5c","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][WPA-EAP-TKIP][ESS]","frequency":"5240","level":"-57","sSid":"PLOCAL"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:5f","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"5240","level":"-58","sSid":"eduroam"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:5b","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"5240","level":"-58","sSid":"SLaMFT"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ea:fc","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][WPA-EAP-TKIP][ESS]","frequency":"5520","level":"-58","sSid":"PLOCAL"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ec:30","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"2437","level":"-59","sSid":"eduroam"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ee:61","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"2412","level":"-59","sSid":"KINGSWAP"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ee:62","capabilities":"[ESS]","frequency":"2412","level":"-59","sSid":"The Cloud"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ee:64","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"2412","level":"-59","sSid":"SLaMFT"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ec:31","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"2437","level":"-60","sSid":"KINGSWAP"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ee:60","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"2412","level":"-60","sSid":"eduroam"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ee:63","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][WPA-EAP-TKIP][ESS]","frequency":"2412","level":"-60","sSid":"PLOCAL"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ec:32","capabilities":"[ESS]","frequency":"2437","level":"-60","sSid":"The Cloud"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ec:34","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"2437","level":"-61","sSid":"SLaMFT"},{"bBsid":"00:42:68:a6:a6:41","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"2462","level":"-62","sSid":"KINGSWAP"},{"bBsid":"00:42:68:a6:a6:42","capabilities":"[ESS]","frequency":"2462","level":"-62","sSid":"The Cloud"},{"bBsid":"00:42:68:a6:a6:43","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][WPA-EAP-TKIP][ESS]","frequency":"2462","level":"-62","sSid":"PLOCAL"},{"bBsid":"00:42:68:a6:a6:44","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"2462","level":"-62","sSid":"SLaMFT"},{"bBsid":"00:42:68:a6:a6:40","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]","frequency":"2462","level":"-62","sSid":"eduroam"},{"bBsid":"00:62:ec:fd:ec:33","capabilities":"[WPA2-EAP
```

Comment: Can you provide the JSON string you're trying to deserialise?

Comment: @StickyMcGinty added but its fairly long

Comment: Is that the **whole** Json? Or did you just cut the rest? It is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clear this in shortly;

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json ="[{\"bBsid\":\"00:62:ec:fd:ea:f0\",\"capabilities\":\"[WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]\",\"frequency\":\"2462\",\"level\":\"-45\",\"sSid\":\"eduroam\"}]"; // Your Json String

        if (json.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            return null;
        }
        YourClassName obj = gson.fromJson(json, YourClassName.class);

return obj;
```

Here, obj is Your Class Object, which is converted into Class Object, Print Log of it & Check it. Hope this will Help you.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason is that the Json string is truncated. Truncation might happen only when `Log` prints it but I think that is not the the case now.

Namely, if you remove the last incomplete `WifiObject` from the Json and add closing `]` it deserializes right, with 34 `WifiObjects`.

You should trace the point where the Json is generated and see what happens in between. I have experienced this same issue but just can not remember what was the reason in my case (will get back if I find it).

I suspect that there is something like storing this long string in `SharedPreferences` but you have not provided code for the Json generation and later manipulation so hard to say anything more specific.